# How does statistical calculation of "similar products/music/..." from customer buying/listening behaviour work?

Tags: python, statistics, data-mining, similarity

I mean product suggestions on Amazon or more specifically similar band recommendation on Last.fm.

Given that you can store the complete listening/buying behaviour of your users (WHO listened to WHAT how OFTEN?), how do you calculate which bands are similar to any given bands, and how much?

I've found some sites on Wikipedia ([Association rule learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning), [Affinity analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinity_analysis)) but I'd like to get some information from a programmer's point of view and preferably some pseudocode or Python code for it.

Given that I have

```
 dic = {
"Alice"   : { "AC/DC" : 2, "The Raconteurs" : 3, "Mogwai" : 1 },
"Bob"     : { "The XX" : 4, "Lady Gaga" : 3, "Mogwai" : 1, "The Raconteurs" : 1 }
"Charlie" : { "AC/DC" : 7, "Lady Gaga" : 7 }
 }
```

where the numbers are play counts, how would I iterate over this to find the similarity of the bands?

Comment: I don't think it's clear what your asking: are you asking what data structures are needed to implement basket analysis?

Comment: Hm, maybe I can edit my question to make it clearer. I'm looking for the algorithm which is used. If it's called basket analysis, you've already helped my in a way. I now found it on Wikipedia under Affinity Analysis. However, I couldn't find pseudocode or Python code for it anywhere.

Comment: @Justin: No, I'm not using a database ... but I'm looking forward to answers which assume I do. I'll probably learn something.

Comment: Great question, IMHO. I’ve always wondered about these sorts of algorithms.

Answer (score 5):

The book "[Programming Collective Intelligence: Building Smart Web 2.0 Applications](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529321)" is a classic and uses Python. Among other things it also deals with recommendation engines.

[image]

Comment: Sweet. Bought, but on oreilly.com as an ePub cos it’s nicer on my iPad that way.

Comment: @Paul: Makes sense, I changed the link to point directly to O'Reilly.

Comment: oh, sorry, that was more for the benefit of Stack Overflow figuring out what affiliate links to have. It would be interesting to know where SO folks prefer to get their books from though.

Comment: I bought it as well now. Had hoped for a direct answer here, but the book has such good reviews, I think it will be totally worth buying. +1.

Answer (score 2):

You might find the [Association Rules](http://orange.biolab.si/doc/ofb/assoc.htm) widget (among others) in [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si/) helpful in getting started.  Another useful package, available with source, is [pysuggest](http://code.google.com/p/pysuggest/) which implements a number of recsys/collaborative filtering algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are talking about is collaborative filtering. As far as I know, Amazon and others uses a Java framework called Apache Mahout, which in a nutshell is a "factory of recommenders" based on user/item data.

Check it out, it's free. However, I'm not sure if it suitable to a Python integration, I'm less than a newbie in that department.

Answer (score 1):

When you have data associating users and products, you implicitly have a bipartite graph between those two sets. The (very sparse) adjacency matrix of that graph is useful. If you do some work with normalizing the length of the columns, then multiply its transpose by the matrix itself, you then in some sense have the item-to-item similarities as they're reflected by the intermediary user base.